# TYPO3 CKEditor – configuration not working

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, yaml, typoscript, typo3-8.7.x

I have an TYPO3 8.7.7 installation and I am using rte_ckeditor. I am trying to configure the editor – but it seems not to work. 
When I set `RTE.default.preset = full` or anything else nothing changes in my backend form.

But I need to configure some individual options. So I set the default preset to my own YAML file (`RTE.default.preset = mytemplate`) which is also registered in my extension ext_localconf.php with

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['mytemplate'] = 'EXT:mytemplate/Configuration/RTE/rte.yaml';
```

I have cleared typo3temp Folder, system caches via backend, all caches via install tool, deactivated and reactivated my template extension.

I also do not change anything in my backend form at the RTE.

The only thing it did sometimes, when I clear the system cache in backend and save the backend form TYPO3 shows me syntax error in my YAML file – which are all solved now, but it also do not show anything again. Just the default RTE...

My YAML file has nothing special... just come classes and the format tags "pre" relaced with "h6"

```
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }

editor:
  config:

    contentsCss: ["EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Public/css/rte/rte.css"]

    format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6"

    stylesSet:
      - { name: "align-left", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6', 'p', 'td', 'th'], attributes: { 'class': 'align-left' }}
      - { name: "align-center", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6', 'p', 'td', 'th'], attributes: { 'class': 'align-center' }}
      - { name: "align-right", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6', 'p', 'td', 'th'], attributes: { 'class': 'align-right' }}
      - { name: "align-justify", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6', 'p', 'td', 'th'], attributes: { 'class': 'align-justify' }}
      - { name: "Headline Stil 1", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6'], attributes: { 'class': 'headline-style-1' }}
      - { name: "Headline Stil 2", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6'], attributes: { 'class': 'headline-style-2' }}
      - { name: "Headline Stil 3", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6'], attributes: { 'class': 'headline-style-3' }}
      - { name: "Headline Stil 4", element: ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','h5', 'h6'], attributes: { 'class': 'headline-style-4' }}
      - { name: "Button-Link Primär", element: ['a'], attributes: { 'class': 'rte-btn-primary' }}
      - { name: "Button-Link Sekundär", element: ['a'], attributes: { 'class': 'rte-btn-secondary' }}
      - { name: "Button-Link Tertiär", element: ['a'], attributes: { 'class': 'rte-btn-tertiary' }}

    toolbarGroups:
      - { name: styles, groups: [ styles, format ] }
      - { name: basicstyles, groups: [ basicstyles ] }
      - { name: paragraph, groups: [ list, indent, blocks, align ] }
      - { name: links, groups: [ links ] }
      - { name: clipboard, groups: [ clipboard, cleanup, undo ] }
      - { name: editing, groups: [ spellchecker ] }
      - { name: insert, groups: [ insert ] }
      - { name: tools, groups: [ table, specialchar ] }
      - { name: document, groups: [ mode ] }

    justifyClasses:
      - align-left
      - align-center
      - align-right
      - align-justify

    extraPlugins:
      - justify

    removePlugins:
      - image

    removeButtons:
      - Anchor
      - Underline
      - Strike
      - Styles
```

What is the trick to get my config working?!

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem... Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Are you using the RTE field in the DCE extension?

Comment: I'm using fluid_content, fluidpages and flux

Comment: Ok maybe the same issue. Check out my answer below.

Comment: Thanks - seems like this is a bug/missing feature in flux. When I use the richtextConfiguration, it throws an error...

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was using DCE Extension – an the preset got ignored. To use any preset use this DCE field Config:

```
<config>
    <type>text</type>
    <rows>5</rows>
    <cols>30</cols>
    <eval>trim,required</eval>
    <enableRichtext>1</enableRichtext>
    <richtextConfiguration>mypreset</richtextConfiguration>
</config>
```

I informed the Ext developer of DCE Ext and he updated the RTE Config "preset" already.

Comment: To get to know which preset are configured in your TYPO3 Installatin look at $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']  in the TYPO3 BE / Configuration. Ad new presets in LocalCongifuration.php in ['RTE']['Presets']['mypreset']